# Structural Type doesn't call correct implementation?

Tags: scala, reflection, structural-typing

I was under the impression that [Structural Types](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#structural-types) use reflection under the hood (indicated by the need to [tell the compiler](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/language.scala#L58) to enable `"-language:reflectiveCalls"`) and that whatever object matches the type will be using it's own version of the function. For example, if I call `.contains` on a `Seq` than it will use the `Seq` version, if I call it on a `String` then it will use the version defined in [StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps) that it gets from `SeqLike`

So in scala 2.10.3, why does this happen:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_79).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> type Containable = { def contains(elem:Any):Boolean }
defined type alias Containable

scala> val myMap: Map[String, Containable] = Map("A" -> "B", "C" -> Seq("A","B"))
myMap: Map[String,Containable] = Map(A -> B, C -> List(A, B))

scala> myMap("A").contains("B")
res0: Boolean = false

scala> myMap("C").contains("B")
res1: Boolean = true

scala> "B".contains("B")
res3: Boolean = true
```

As you can see, a `String`.contains(`String`) returns true for itself, but not if it's called while being interpretted as a `Containable` type, even though that matches the defined method in the StringOps class.

I have the feeling this has to do with the implementation of `==` since `.contains` documentation says:

> true if this sequence has an element that is equal (as determined by ==) to elem, false otherwise.

this feeling is compounded by the results of checking the type via `isInstanceOf`

```
scala> val aVal = myMap("A")
aVal: Containable = B

scala> aVal.isInstanceOf[String]
res5: Boolean = false

scala> aVal.isInstanceOf[Seq[_]]
res6: Boolean = true
```

In response to the comment about compiler error, here is a [screencast of my terminal showing this working](http://screencast.com/t/wIwg5MaER)

Comment: Are you sure you've tried it like this? In Scala 2.11 I get a type missmatch in the line where you instantiate the map. This is due to neither String nor Seq having a method contains(Any). Their contains methods have different signatures. So if this typechecks in scala 2.10 this would be a bug.

Comment: This runs in scala 2.10.3, the version is noted in the REPL

Comment: @dth I've added a video screencast of my REPL for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you insert the `String`s into your `Map`, they get converted into a `WrappedString`, because `String` doesn't have a method with the signature you defined in `Containable`.

```
scala> implicitly[String => Containable]
res10: String => Containable = <function1>

scala> res10("s")
res11: Containable = s

scala> res11.getClass
res12: Class[_ <: AnyRef] = class scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString
```

In Scala 2.10.x `WrappedString` has a method `contains(elem: Any): Boolean`. It checks whether `elem` is an element of the collection on which `contains` is invoked. A `WrappedString` represents a collection of `Char`s, so that method will never return true if you give it a `String`.
In scala 2.11.x that `contains` method has been changed so it only accepts `Char`s.

`String` itself has a method `contains(elem: java.lang.CharSequence): Boolean`. A `String` is a `CharSequence` so when you call `contains("B")` on a `String` that method will be called and the `String` will not get converted to a `WrappedString`.

Comment: Oh wow. Do you know _why_ it get's converted into a WrappedString?

Comment: I've just noticed, this change is deeper. WrappedString implements SeqLike and the signature of the contains method of SeqLike has changed in Scala 2.11.

Comment: The reason, why it is converted, is, that String does not have a method contains(Any) but only contains(CharSequence). As you specified explicitly the type Containable the compiler had to convert it.

Comment: sorry I should have been more specific, I know that it is converted because it doesn't have a `contains` method, but my question was more why does it turn into `WrappedString` and not `StringOps`, I'm assuming it's an implementation detail in the Map?

Comment: Ah nevermind, StringOps.toCollection converts it via WrappedString, so the conversion to use .contains from a collection trait like that probably does it and there's no way to get around that it seems. So it seems if I want to store both strings and lists of strings in a map I will have to pattern match the result rather than type it with Containable. Too bad, the typing seemed so clean.